# Margin em percentual é relativo a quê?

Tags: html, css, css3

Estou atualmente vendo um [video no youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eOG90Q8EfRo&spfreload=10%20Message%3A%20JSON%20Parse%20error%3A%20Unexpected%20EOF%20(url%3A%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DeOG90Q8EfRo)) sobre como criar um `responsive website`. Ele, a um certo momento (minuto 24.55), estabelece o margin duma imagem em percentual, em vez de usar os normais pixels. O que não entendo é a que largura ou comprimento a percentual é relativa, ou seja estes `2%` são em relação a que largura? E o `0` serve exatamente para quê? (Tenho uma certa intuição, mas com os css as intuicões, sinceramente, servem a pouco).

```
.mainheader img{
    width:30%;
    height:auto; /* automatically determines the height*/
    margin: 2% 0;
}
```

Em geral, os percentuais são em relação a quê?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O valor percentual é relativo ao bloco superior (neste caso o bloco que contém o elemento em questão).

No teu caso a margem das imagens dentro de um elemento da classe `.mainheader` distará em `2%` do topo e do "rodapé".

**Exemplo:**

Na imagem seguinte temos o elemento superior definido com 900px fixos de largura, e um elemento filho que tem como largura (`width`) 50% do elemento superior (o que correspondera a 450px).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quanto ao `0` que vem após ao valor definido em percentagem serve para definir a margem dada em relação ao topo e ao rodapé(*bottom*). [Aqui](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) poderás perceber melhor.

---

Eis as formas para a definição da margem(usei `pixel` mais poderá ser outra unidade):

```
.elementoTeste { margin: 2px }         /* all margins set to 2px */
.elementoTeste { margin: 1px 2px }     /* top & bottom = 1px, right & left = 2px */
.elementoTeste { margin: 1px 2px 3px } /* top=1px, right=2px, bottom=3px, left=2px */
```

Answer (score 5):

É relativo ao comprimento bloco superior.

```css
#yellow {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
.red {
  width: 50%;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.green {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div id="yellow">
  <div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="red">
      <div class="green"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
<div id="white">
  <div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="red">
      <div class="green"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: é relativo ao atributo superior. Repara no 2º bloco azul.

Comment: Bom resposta, mas positivei ela mais pela demonstração desse recurso de executar código diretamente no post ;)

Answer (score 2):

Sobre o uso de porcentagem:

Como disseram, é referente ao bloco superior, mas tem que tomar alguns cuidados, pois a medida de referência é do primeiro bloco superior **QUE TIVER UMA MEDIDA ESTABELECIDA**, ou seja, se a camada imediatamente anterior que **FOR UM BLOCO** não tiver uma medida válida, a porcentagem usará a anterior como referência, desde que se haja um valor usável...

Sobre o "margin: 2% **0**":

Algumas propriedades do CSS são unidas em apenas uma, como, por exemplo:

`margin:` = `margin-top:` + `margin-right:` + `margin-bottom:` + `margin-left:`

Segue exemplo:

```
.AllMargin { 
    margin: 50px; // top-right-bottom-left: 50px
}  

.MarginVertical { 
    margin: 50px 0; // top-bottom: 50px, right-left: 0
}

.MarginHorizontal { 
    margin: 0 50px; // top-bottom: 0, right-left: 50px
}

.TresMargins { 
    margin: 100px 10px 50px; // top: 100px, right-left: 10px, bottom: 50px
}
.QuatroMargins{
    margin: 5px 10px 20px 30px; // top: 5px, right: 10px, bottom: 20px, left: 30px
}
```

O mesmo acontece em propriedades como: `padding`, `border`, `border-style`, `border-color`, sempre lembrando que a ordem para os 4 parâmetros dessas propriedades é  `top right bottom left` (sentido horário, a partir do `top`)...

Outras propriedades que agregam várias propriedades dentro é o `box-shadow`, o `background` e o `filter`, por exemplo, mas nesses os parâmetros são outros.

Answer (score 0):

No caso especificado seria relativo a 100% da ".mainheader", ou seja, a img ficaria afastada 2% no topo e no rodapé dos 100% da mainheader

Comment: Sim,

Exemplos:
<pre>
<code>
margin: 10px 30px;
/* É igual a margin-top: 10px; margin-botton: 10px; margin-left: 30px; e margin-right: 30px;*/

margin: 10px 30px 15px;
/* É igual a margin-top: 10px; margin-botton: 15px; margin-left: 30px; e margin-right: 30px;*/

margin: 10px;
/* É igual a margin-top: 10px; margin-botton: 10px; margin-left: 10px; e margin-right: 10px;*/
</code>
</pre>

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

Comment: @Aluisio http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @AluisioMartinsJunior, creio que na verdade a resposta do Broly é NÃO, pois o `0` após ao valor definido só sera aplicado às margens laterais.

Comment: Neste caso, margem esquerda e direita

Comment: @Cold tem razão, não havia lido o "baixa", realmente é somente esquerda e direita!